# IntToStr undeclared identifier error

Tags: delphi

I want to display certain integers in a memo, listbox or whatever. I've tried a memo, listbox and showmessage() but each throws incompatibility error between string and integers.

This is where it starts going wrong:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add('Physical Functioning: '+PhysFunc div PhysCount);
```

PhysFunc and PhysCount are integers calculated further up. I've tried, e.g.:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add('Physical Functioning: '+IntToStr(PhysFunc div PhysCount));
```

and:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr('Physical Functioning: '+PhysFunc div PhysCount));
```

and:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(('Physical Functioning: '+PhysFunc div PhysCount).AsString);
```

And the same things with a ListBox and showmessage(). But none work. IntToStr returns E2003 undeclared identifier and .AsString returns the error, integer does not contain a member 'AsString'. Are there any alternatives?

I'm using an SDI application in Delphi - could that be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: `IntToStr` is declared in the `SysUtils` unit, just add it to your uses clause.

Comment: @CosminPrund The problem seems to be about incompatibilities. So, I assume that he declared the SysUtils unit already. Or that it was pre-declared when he creatd the project/ unit.

Comment: Memo1.Lines.Add('Physical Functioning: '+IntToStr(PhysFunc div PhysCount)); This one must work!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling the `Add` method of `TStrings` which receives a single parameter of type `string`. You need to concatenate a string and an integer. In order to do so you must convert the integer into a string.

You attempted to do that using `IntToStr` which is a perfectly reasonable approach. But that failed because the compiler could not locate `IntToStr`. Now, `IntToStr` is declared in the `SysUtils` unit and so you must add that unit to your `uses` clause.

However, I'd probably use [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.Format) here. Like `IntToStr`, this function is declared in `SysUtils` which you must use.

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Physical Functioning: %d', [PhysFunc div PhysCount]));
```

For more details on format read the documentation for [format strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.Format#Format_Strings).

Answer (score 0):

The first line of code doesn't work because *PhysFunc div PhysCount* is an integer and it is not converted to a string.

The second line of code should work, but I would check the actual values of *PhysFunc* and *PhysCount*. Is it possible that *PhysCount* is, somehow, equal to 0?

The third line of code doesn't work because *IntToStr* expects integers and you gave him, among others, a string.

The fourth line of code doesn't work because, as you said, **integer does not contain a member 'AsString'**

You also said:

*IntToStr returns E2003 undeclared identifier*

That could also be the problem: one of the two variables is not declared. Make sure that both of them are declared in the *var* section.

To conclude:

1. Check to see if both variables are declared;
2. Check to see if *PhysCount* <>0 at the time of the evaluation.

Good luck!

Comment: "integer does not contain a member 'AsString'" - XE3 introduces a new feature called "record helpers" that allows helper classes to be implemented for intrinsic types, like integers and strings.  So it is possible to create a custom `helper for Integer` type that implements an `AsString()` method (or any other method you want).

Comment: I didn't knew that :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the uses if there is the **SysUtils**  included.

Comment: And how does that answer the question? Please explain.